# JobScheduler is not working in android Version Oreo

Tags: java, android, service, android-jobscheduler

Trying to send the mobile's data  (SMS, call logs and location) to the server after every few minutes through foreground services through and I use JOB SCHEDULER to send. The data is in my local database of every action. 
But after every few minutes job freezes and all the background services automatically stop.

Answer (score 1):

in Android Oreo minimum period interval is 15 minutes . Set your interval to 15 minutes then try again